# create dashboard docker container to be deployed on AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, dashboard

I created a Dash dasboard that I want to deploy on AWS.

the tree I use is the following

```
app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.scripts.config.serve_locally = True
app.css.config.serve_locally = True
...
...
some plots
...
if __name__ == '__main__':


    app.run_server()
```

This dashboard runs locally

I created this Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7-slim
# continuumio/miniconda3
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY ./somefile.csv /usr/src/app/somefile.csv
COPY ./requirements.txt /tmp/ 
COPY ./app /usr/src/app
RUN apt update \
    && apt-get install -y libglib2.0-0 libsm6 libxrender1 libxext6 libgl1-mesa-dev

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r /tmp/requirements.txt



# ENTRYPOINT [ "python3" ]
CMD [ "python","application.py" ]


EXPOSE 8080
```

and then i build the image

```
docker build -t tp_dashboard .
```

If then I go inside the container

```
 docker container run -it tp_dashboard bash
```

and run the application.

I cannot access the dashboard on the browser

what is wrong?

If then I push the image to AWS ECR and then create a Fargate Cluster I also cannot access the dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

That docker command isn't correct. To start the app locally, try this:

```
docker container run tp_dashboard -p 8080:8080
```

Once it is running you should be able to access it at `http://localhost:8080`.

---

> "If then I push the image to AWS ECR and then create a Fargate Cluster
> I also cannot access the dashboard."

Until you get it running locally, there's no point in even trying it on AWS. If you get it running locally, but still have issues on AWS, then post a new question and include your AWS task definition, load balancer settings, and any other relevant information in the question

Comment: docker container run --name dashboard -p 8080:8080 tp_dashboard
Dash is running on http://127.0.0.1:8050/

 * Serving Flask app "application" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:8050/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)

Comment: doesn't open on the browser

Comment: Well I said to use 8080 because your Dockerfile has `EXPOSE 8080` but apparently it's running on port `8050` instead. You need to reconcile that.

Comment: Try `docker container run tp_dashboard -p 8050:8050` and then opening http://127.0.0.1:8050/

Comment: even if i expose 8050 in the Dockerfile, rebuild the image, and run the container that way still nothing

Comment: changin to app.run_server(host='0.0.0.0', port=8050), did the trick

Answer (score 0):

I changed the Dockerfile to:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.10

# LABEL maintainer="Chris von Csefalvay <chris@chrisvoncsefalvay.com>"

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y python3 python3-dev python3-pip
# RUN apt-get install -y gunicorn

COPY ./workouts_bruvio_2020.csv /app/workouts_bruvio_2020.csv
COPY ./requirements.txt /tmp/ 
COPY ./ /app

RUN pip3 install -r /tmp/requirements.txt

COPY ./ /app
WORKDIR /app

# CMD [ "gunicorn" "--bind" "0.0.0.0:80" "wsgi" ]
CMD gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:80 wsgi
```

and changed the main application.
the Dash application – effectively, a Flask app – will communicate with clients using gunicorn, a WSGI HTTP server application.

this solved the issue of the container not able to run and also the deploy to AWS.
I pushed the image to ECR and then created a custom ECS with Fargate and default option.